# How to make ACL, which can managed from web-interface (for example)?

Tags: symfony

There is ROLES and access_control, hardcoded in security.yml. But i wanna have ability to change set of privileges given to certain roles, create new roles, and even give some role (which can be granted to user, who are not familiar with programming) ability to make same things.
Obviously, i must have ability to manage roles and access control from web-interface. And for that, i must store roles name and privileges, according to that role, in database.

How can i do that?

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have basically have any role you want you just need to implement the interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface in your User entity and return the list of roles for that user in the getRoles() method.

If you haven't implemented the UserInterface in your User entity check the Symfony 2 Security documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#loading-users-from-the-database

And also the [UserInterface API](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html) for the getRoles() method specification.